# Как добавить в пункт меню drupal 7 html код?

Tags: php, drupal

Работаю над темой для Drupal 7, основанной на bootstrap. Специальной базовой темы не использую, всё делаю вручную.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в меню ссылка на главную страницу выглядела в виде glyphicon'овского домика:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
```

Пытаюсь реализовать это так:

```
function imit_menu_link__main_menu ($variables) {
$element = $variables['element'];
$sub_menu = '';

if ($element['#below']) {
  $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
}

if ($element['#href'] == '<front>') {
  $element['#title'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>';
}

$output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href']);
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Но в итоге тег `span` выводится как обычный текст.
Как заставить его выводиться HTML-элементом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо разрешить преобразовывать в html

```
if ($element['#href'] == '<front>') {
  $element['#title'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = true; //разрешаем вывод в html
}
```

Больше параметров, которые можно передать через #localized_options смотрите [здесь](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x) - туда он попадает как массив $options. Кстати, есть модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_html для простого решения подобных задач.